# Cordova plugin: call custom plugin's method from another class (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I've developed a custom `Cordova plugin`. I can successfully call it from `JS`, but I also need to call it from another class (native code). How can I do it?

*How can I call `showImageURL` method of my custom plugin?*

// MyCustomPlugin.m

```
@implementation MyCustomPlugin

    - (void) showImageURL:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

        if (_fullScreenImageView)
            return;

        NSString *fullPath = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"url"];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www/application/app/%@", fullPath]];
        _fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        _fullScreenImageView.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        UIViewController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        [controller.view addSubview:_fullScreenImageView];
        [controller.view bringSubviewToFront:_fullScreenImageView];

    }
```

// AnotherClass.m

```
@implementation AnotherClass


- (void) foo {

    MyCustomPlugin *splashScreen = [[MyCustomPlugin alloc] init];
    [splashScreen showImageURL:]; // <<- what params should I pass to `showImageURL`?

}
```

p.s. this is how I call it from the JS: `window.FullScreenImage.showImageURL('img/bar.png');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to abstract away the Cordova interface so you can call it as a simple Objective-C function:

```
@implementation MyCustomPlugin

    - (void) showImageURL:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
        NSString *fullPath = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"url"];
        [self _showImageURL:fullPath];
    }

    - (void) _showImageURL:(NSString*)fullPath{

        if (_fullScreenImageView)
            return;

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www/application/app/%@", fullPath]];
        _fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        _fullScreenImageView.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        UIViewController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        [controller.view addSubview:_fullScreenImageView];
        [controller.view bringSubviewToFront:_fullScreenImageView];

    }


@implementation AnotherClass

- (void) foo {

    MyCustomPlugin *splashScreen = [[MyCustomPlugin alloc] init];
    [splashScreen _showImageURL:@"path/to/some/image.png"];

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Only you have a duplicate declaration of the method `showImageURL`